I can't upload the keyboard module into my python idle code it keeps saying the module is not uploaded on Mac
I'm trying to make a python code that when I press space it would play an mp3 file and then when I press it again it would play the following one. But when I put import keyboard this pops up in IDLE shell. Problem is that I put the keyboard file into my folder already, I'm completely lost. Someone help me please, I'm just started coding :D Thank you. it says keyboard is not defined when I type import keyboard.
I'll show you my code (it said my code wasn't formatted correct idk how to make it right :))
(they told me indent?)
Can someone teach me how to upload a module into python (IDLE??) so that I could import it into my code and use it? Thank you!

It looks like you need to ad the keyboard module to Python. Here's how:
Open the command prompt or terminal and type the following command to install a module via pip (Python’s package installer):
pip install <module_name>

Replace <module_name> with the actual name of the module you want to install. For example, to install the numpy module, type:
pip install numpy

If it is a program from another file you are trying to add to the new program, you can put
from <full path> import <function>

where the from is the path of the file and the function is the name of the function you are adding. I believe you will have to use the first part, not this though.
There are other ways to do this but this is the preferred method. Hope this helps!


Have you install the keyboard package with pip install command?

I think you have named one of your file with 'keyboard' name. Python interpreter may think that you are import your custom module instead of installed keyboard package.


Solution:

Create virtual environment
Install keyboard package there
Verify the installation:
If it works, then increment it to your logic of playing music.

Here is simple code snippet to follow:
import keyboard
import playsound

mp3_file = "file1.mp3" # store it in the same folder where you run the program


def play_mp3():
    playsound.playsound(mp3_file)


keyboard.on_press_key("space", play_next_mp3)


keyboard.wait("esc")


Best regards,
Sardor
